# How to troubleshoot quickbooks-ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, quickbooks-online

I have a Rails app set up with the `quickbooks-ruby` gem.

Oauth seems to be working—there are no errors, I follow the Quickbooks login in a pop-up, and I get a confirmation that the account is connected. No errors.

However, in my audit log on Quickbooks Online, there is not indication that I have logged in.

And when I follow the steps to try to get a list of customers, I get this error:

`undefined method 'get' for "qyprd...":String`

Which may or may not be a different problem.

This is the code:

```
def index
  @customers = Customer.all
  service = Quickbooks::Service::Customer.new
  service.company_id = session[:realm_id]
  service.access_token = session[:token]

  customers = service.query()
end
```

I don't understand why it isn't working, or how to troubleshoot the issue.

Answer (score 0):

From the above code I see you are not passing the query in last but one line. Query should look something like this i.e customers.query("Select Id, GivenName From Customer")

To understand why it isn't working and to troubleshoot the issue you can use begin and rescue.

```
begin
    oauth_client = OAuth::AccessToken.new($qb_oauth_consumer, token, secret)
    service = Quickbooks::Service::Customer.new(:access_token => oauth_client, :company_id => realm_id)
    customers = customers.query("Select Id, GivenName From Customer")
rescue Exception => e
    # e.message will show response of quickbooks for you request 
    puts e.message
    # e.message.inspect will show logs
    puts e.backtrace.inspect  
end
```

You can also try your queries on API explorer and see if get the result set you want.

Comment: You do not need to pass an argument to `.query()` for it to work.  That doesn't make sense.